# How can i use group by a column 1 and get the most frequent occurance of column 2 in the same output in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have got data

[image]

I want output like this

[image]

I tried

```
SELECT email, time_of_day,COUNT(time_day) AS numtrips FROM internal.data100k
GROUP   BY  email,  time_of_day  desc limit 26;
```

and many nested but getting error and no idea on what the logic be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT email, action, 
  SUM(time_of_day_repetition) total_individual_action_count,
  ARRAY_AGG(
    STRUCT(time_of_day AS time_of_day_with_max_repetition, time_of_day_repetition AS max_repetition) 
    ORDER BY time_of_day_repetition DESC LIMIT 1
  )[OFFSET(0)].*
FROM (
  SELECT email, action, time_of_day, 
    COUNT(1) time_of_day_repetition  
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY email, action, time_of_day
)
GROUP BY email, action
```